# gitlab-runner docker-machine error

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-machine

im having an issue when i try to register a runner, gitlabrunner v10.6.0, ubuntu 16.04

here are my printenv:

```
SHELL_RUNNER_EXECUTOR=shell
SHELL_RUNNER_TAG_LIST=***,aws,shell,docker-builder
CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.***.com/
DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_TAG_LIST=***,aws,docker,runner
DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_EXECUTOR=docker+machine
REGISTRATION_TOKEN=***
DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_NAME=***-docker-runner
```

this is my register call:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  -u $CI_SERVER_URL \
  -r $REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --tag-list $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_TAG_LIST \
  --executor $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_EXECUTOR \
  --name $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_NAME \
  --locked "false" \
  --docker-image "alpine" \
  --machine-machine-driver "amazonec2" \
  --machine-machine-name "gitlab-docker-machine-%s" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=***" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-region=us-west-2" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-vpc-id=***" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-3a21a573" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.medium" \
  --machine-machine-options "engine-storage-driver=overlay" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-use-private-address=true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-tags=runner-manager-name,gitlab-aws-autoscaler,gitlab,true,gitlab-runner-autoscale,true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-zone=b" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-spot-price=0.05" \
  --machine-idle-nodes "1" \
  --machine-max-builds "100" \
  --request-concurrency "10" \
  --output-limit 16384 \
  --docker-privileged \
  --cache-type "s3" \
  --cache-s3-server-address "s3.amazonaws.com" \
  --cache-s3-bucket-name "***-gitlab-runner-cache" \
  --cache-s3-bucket-location "us-west-2" \
  --cache-cache-shared "true"
```

this is the error:

> PANIC: The docker-image needs to be entered

Answer (score 2):

Making these changes fixed the issue:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  -u $CI_SERVER_URL \
  -r $REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --tag-list $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_TAG_LIST \
  --executor $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_EXECUTOR \
  --name $DOCKER_MACHINE_RUNNER_NAME \
  --locked=false \
  --docker-tlsverify=false \
  --docker-image=alpine \
  --machine-machine-driver "amazonec2" \
  --machine-machine-name "gitlab-docker-machine-%s" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=***" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-region=us-west-2" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-vpc-id=***" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-subnet-id=***" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.medium" \
  --machine-machine-options "engine-storage-driver=overlay" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-use-private-address=true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-tags=runner-manager-name,gitlab-aws-autoscaler,gitlab,true,gitlab-runner-autoscale,true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-zone=b" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true" \
  --machine-machine-options "amazonec2-spot-price=0.05" \
  --machine-idle-nodes "1" \
  --machine-max-builds "100" \
  --request-concurrency "10" \
  --output-limit 16384 \
  --docker-privileged \
  --cache-type "s3" \
  --cache-s3-server-address "s3.amazonaws.com" \
  --cache-s3-bucket-name "***-gitlab-runner-cache" \
  --cache-s3-bucket-location "us-west-2" \
  --cache-cache-shared=true
```